# SPRESENSEのプレイリスト再生において同じ曲が何度も流れてしまう問題について

Tags: spresense

現在、Spresense上で下記サイトのSpresenseArduinoチュートリアルにおけるプレイリストの再生を試みています。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html
手順通りに作業を行ないリスト表示を行なったところ、下記画像のように1曲目が各曲の合間に表示されます。実際に動作させた場合にも、1曲目が合間に必ず流れてしまいます。
[image: Spresenseシリアルモニター上での曲のリスト表示]

この現象はSpresense Reference Boardのバージョン2.5.0以降で発生し、2.4.0では正常に動作することを確認できました。どのようにすればバージョン2.5.0以降でも正常に動作するようになるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDKv2.4とSDKv2.5との差分を解析してみたところ、
内部で自動生成されているalias_list_alltrack.binファイルのサイズと中身が異なっていて、
これがプレイリストが正しく表示されない原因のようです。

スケッチ上でこのファイルを作り直せば、この問題を回避することができそうです。

1. `player_playlist.ino` スケッチに `update_alias_file()` 関数を追加する

```cpp
static void update_alias_file(const char *dirname)
{
  char     fname[64];
  File     file;
  uint32_t size;
  uint32_t *buffer;
  uint32_t i;

  sprintf(fname, "%s/alias_list_alltrack.bin", dirname);

  /* Read alias file into buffer */
  file = File(fname, FILE_READ);
  size = file.size();
  buffer = (uint32_t*)malloc(size);
  file.read(buffer, size);
  file.close();

  /* Create the correct alias file */
  if (buffer[1] == 0x0) {
    unlink(fname);
    file = File(fname, FILE_WRITE);
    for (i = 0; i < size / 4; i += 2) {
      file.write((uint8_t*)&buffer[i], 4);
    }
    file.close();
  }
  free(buffer);
  thePlaylist.select(Playlist::ListTypeAllTrack, "");
}
```

2. `thePlaylist.init()` の後ろに `update_alias_file()` の呼び出しを追加する

```cpp
  success = thePlaylist.init(playlist_dirname);
  if (!success) {
    printf("ERROR: no exist playlist file %s/TRACK_DB.CSV\n",
           playlist_dirname);
    while (1);
  }

  update_alias_file(playlist_dirname); // ★★★ 追加
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。提案していただいた方法を試したのですが、最後の曲を再生した際に1曲目に戻らず、エラーとなってしまう問題と、1曲ずつのリピート再生で必ず停止してしまい連続して再生されないという問題が発生してしまいました。

Comment: シリアルモニタから「r」キーを押してリピートモードをRepeat=OnにしたりRepeat=Offにしたりできますが、Repeat=Onの状態なのにリピートされないという問題でしょうか？私は特に問題無くリピート再生できています。エラーが発生しているとなると自分が回答した問題とは別件の問題っぽいですね。

Comment: Repeatができない問題はTRACK_DB_CSVファイルを作成し直したら正常に動作しました。